# Find previous non-zero pairs for each column-pairs combination and create separate column for those using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
A     B
1     1
0     0
2     3
0     0
0     0
5     4
0     3
0     0
```

I want to add two more columns with following conditions:
for every A and B pairs previous non-zero pair values will be added in other two columns but for first time it will be zeros in both,

For example the output will be like:

```
A     B    C    D
1     1    0    0
0     0    1    1
2     3    1    1
0     0    2    3
0     0    2    3
5     4    2    3
0     3    5    4
0     0    0    3
```

I can do it using loop, but I want least execution time in most pythonic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I break down the steps

```
mask=df.A.ne(0)|df.B.ne(0) # get the target row 
df1=df[mask] # filter from original df
df1.index+=1 # get the index increase by one 
df1.columns=['C','D'] # reassign the columns 
pd.concat([df,df1],axis=1).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int) # using ffill
Out[569]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  0  0
1  0  0  1  1
2  2  3  1  1
3  0  0  2  3
4  0  0  2  3
5  5  4  2  3
6  0  3  5  4
7  0  0  0  3
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe one way is to just shift `A` and `B`, use that as your `C` and `D` column, replace rows where both are 0 with `nan`, forward fill, and finally replace the top `NaN` with 0:

```
df[['C','D']] = df[['A','B']].shift()

df.loc[(df[['C','D']] == 0).all(1), ['C','D']] = np.nan

df.ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)

   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  0  0
1  0  0  1  1
2  2  3  1  1
3  0  0  2  3
4  0  0  2  3
5  5  4  2  3
6  0  3  5  4
7  0  0  0  3
```